# How to show/hide print menu(top) item by a condition?

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I try to make an report, that print invoice only if it's type is 'in_invoice'

I use standard case

```xml
<report
    id="account_att"
    model="account.invoice"
    string="Att"
    report_type="qweb-pdf"
    name="account.report_att"
    attachment="('Att'+(object.number or '').replace('/','')+'.pdf')"
    print_report_name="'Att for '+(object._get_printed_report_name())"
/>
```

How can I check if object type is 'in_invoice'?
I've tried to add

```
menu="(True if object.type == 'in_invoice' else False)"
```

But I get error while install - it seems, menu doesn't recieve object.

How can I change visibility?

Comment: I suggest you use a button to print your report and put the attribute invisible when type is 'in_invoice', and dont register your report by *<report*

Comment: Yes, solution with <button> can be, but is there no way to do it with <report>?